# GORM: Inserting *Big.Int into a NUMERIC column (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm having issues getting a database insert to work with gorm.

```
type T struct {
PoolAddress_     string `json:"pool_address" gorm:"column:pool_address"`
BlockNumber_     uint64 `json:"blockNumber" gorm:"column:block_number"`
TxHash_          string `json:"txnHashC" gorm:"column:transaction_hash"` 
TransactionHash_ string `json:"transactionHash"`                        
OldPrice_      *big.Int `json:"old_price" gorm:"column:old_price"`
NewPrice_      *big.Int `json:"new_price" gorm:"column:new_price"`
KeeperAddress_ string   `json:"keeper_address" gorm:"column:keeper_address"`
Source_        string   `json:"source" gorm:"column:source"`
GasPrice_  uint64 `json:"gasPrice" gorm:"column:gas_price"`
GasTipCap_ uint64 `json:"GasTipCap" gorm:"column:gas_tip_cap"`
GasFeeCap_ uint64 `json:"GasFeeCap" gorm:"column:gas_fee_cap"`
GasUsed_   uint64 `json:"gasUsed" gorm:"column:gas_used"`
BlockTimestamp_ uint64 `json:"blockTimestamp" gorm:"column:block_timestamp"`
```

}

When GORM goes to handle it I get;

```
[debug] Inserting into table
{000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000c42778b0248d4630b7a792dddea2af5094639e9b 4351477 0xc5d846bea7a43ce79ec5dfbe6ed8565e9d82753293300581eb57175b1cfd9f04 0xc5d846bea7a43ce79ec5dfbe6ed8565e9d82753293300581eb57175b1cfd9f04 46008860000000000000000000000000000000000 45868020000000000000000000000000000000000 0x1A5E4Fc790fa234954d9AD765314676dF79aB601 Arbitrum 50000000000 50000000000 50000000000 12500000 1631463094}
Failed to insert into the database! invalid field found for struct github.com/mycelium-ethereum/myc/types/ethereum/etl/log/ocr/Tracer/v1.T's field OldPrice_, need to define a valid foreign key for relations or it need to implement the Valuer/Scanner interface
```

This is really frustrating because I need these fields to be bigInts but GORM doesn't seem to want to let me even though I know the NUMERIC can hold the value on the database. I've looked at the valuer/scanner interfaces but they seem to want to return basic go types which obviously wouldn't work either.

I need the values to be a numeric, I cannot store this as text/bytes/etc.

Comment: Instead of `*big.Int` you can use [`pgtype.Numeric`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgtype?utm_source=godoc#Numeric), it itself wraps `*big.Int` and also implements the `Valuer`/`Scanner` interfaces.

Comment: Or, you can embed `big.Int` in a struct type that you declared and have that struct type implement the two interfaces. Up to you.

Comment: This seems to be using pgx, will this also function with GORM?

Comment: Any type that implements Valuer/Scanner interfaces will work with gorm.